# browser (Firefox/Chrome) doesn't show javascript errors from embedded code

Tags: javascript, console

Lately, I have noticed that when I have a certain error in my (embedded) javascript code, it doesn't show up in the browser's console and I have to "guess" where the error comes from.

When I run the same code in the debugger console of the browsers, I can easily get specific error messages, debug them and so on.

For example:

**mycode.js**

```
var a = 0;
var b = 1 / a;
```

**mypage.html**

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="mycode.js"></script>
...
```

Normally, I should get an error saying that dividing by zero is not allowed or something like that. Instead I don't get any errors in the browser and the code is just not working.

Everything I find about this error when searching on the web, is talking about enabling the errors in the browsers and things like that, but I have no problem with obviously, because it happens on both browsers the same way AND, as I said, when running the same code in the debugger's console, I get the errors like I should.